# {exp:search:keywords} filtering out insignificant words

Tags: expressionengine

With my current project I need to display the exact search phrase entered on the results/no-results pages.

However the {exp:search:keywords} variable seems to have insignificant keywords removed.

“Who am I?” becomes “who am”

I understand why this is the case but for the purposes of this particular website I need the exact phrase.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this ? Please let there be a workaround...

I am using the Simple Search module in 2.7.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/system/expressionengine/modules/search/mod.search.php:236 (v2.7.0)

```
//$original_keywords = $this->keywords;
$original_keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
```